# Return Page From A Method

Tags: c#, automation

Dears,

now i am writing a function in my automation framework. the function will return another page based on some conditions i will decide which page i should return.

lets say i have login_page.cs and register_Page.cs

i have a function that will return either instance of login_page or instance from register_Page

```
public XXX test()

{
if(1)
return new login_Page();

else
return new register_Page();

}
```

what should be the type of XXX?

Comment: What is the project type. Windows forms? WPF? Use better tags.

Comment: i created class library project visual C#

Answer (score 0):

```
public System.Web.UI.Page Test()
{
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are doing and why you are doing it. But As a general answer to this question you have two different classes and want a function to be able to return each. In this situation you create an Interface:

```
public Interface IForm{}
```

Then you inherit the classes from it:

```
public class Form1:IForm
{
}
public class Form2:IForm
{
}
```

And then you can create a function that returns like this:

```
public IForm test()
{
    if(true)
        return new Form1();
    else
        return new Form2();
}
```